# I am trying to create a union query in Access but the union query changes formatting of a field

Tags: sql, ms-access, formatting

I am trying to create a union query of 2 tables but when I create the union query the formatting for certain fields changes. I have checked the formatting of the fields in the original tables and both are set to fixed with 2 as the decimal spaces allowed. When the union is created the field ends up giving me numbers such as 3.62E-5. I assumed that this should be considered 0 or maybe even 0.01 but the formatting for this field gets changed.

Thanks for the help

I have tried formatting the original tables fields in the way I would like the union query to produce the desired result just am not sure what i need to change, I am not great with SQL and am currently just at the beginning stage of learning.

Attempted SQL

```
SELECT * FROM [FileName1]
UNION ALL Select * From [FileName2]
UNION ALL Select * From [FileName3]
UNION ALL Select * From [FileName4]
```

Comment: Format settings do not carry over to UNION query. You could use Round() function to force rounding to 2 decimal places. Why do you have two tables that require UNION to begin with?

Comment: I am not aware of another way to combine the two tables. It really is 4-5 tables but i figured that if I can figure out how to work the format on the two of them, then I could easily fix the format problem when the other tables are added.

Comment: For the Round() function could you give an example of the coding that I should use for this? As such, "Select * From [TableName], Round([FieldName])?

Comment: So why multiple tables and not just one table with another field for a category identifier? Often a UNION query is essentially building dataset that should already be a single table. Edit question to show sample data and your attempted SQL.

Comment: I need to export the data once it is combined, and my understanding was that creating a query was the best way to combine the data so that all tables would end up together and therefore become one dataset. I could definitely be misunderstanding as I have not been working with SQL or Access for more than a week or so.

Comment: I also understand this is probably not the correct format for the SQL as Union might have to be on its own line, but Access was accepting this and everything came out right besides the format of certain fields.

Comment: Whether or not a UNION is appropriate depends on relationships. Can use * wildcard if you want all fields and tables have all the SAME fields in SAME order. This is looking more like should be one table to begin with. Hard to advise without knowing your data. UNION (or UNION ALL) keyword does not have to be on own line.

Comment: Correction: to use * wildcard, field names don't have to be same name nor even same types but must be same number of fields in all tables.

Comment: SQL for SELECT could be like: `SELECT tablename.*, Round(fieldname, 2) AS SomeName FROM tablename;`.

Comment: Also, calculate a field in each SELECT line to identify source table and serve as a category identfier: `SELECT tablename1.*, Round(fieldname, 2) AS SomeName, "T1" AS Cat FROM tablename1`. The alias field names only have to be in the first SELECT line.

Answer (score 1):

First, formatting fields in tables only influences how values are *displayed*, not the values themselves.

Next, a complete guide for union queries exists:

[Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

Also, if you receive values like 3.62E-5 it indicates, that you use Double or Single as the data type. If you ever only need two decimals, change the data type of these numeric fields to *Currency*.

Finally, if you need any post handling of the results, you can use the union query as a *subquery* in a query that applies formatting or calculations, like:

```sql
Select 
    Field1, Field2, Round(Field3, 2), Format(Field4, 'Percent'), FieldN 
From
    (Select * FROM [FileName1]
    UNION ALL 
    Select * From [FileName2]
    UNION ALL 
    Select * From [FileName3]
    UNION ALL 
    Select * From [FileName4])
```